# DataSource getConnection new connection or existing connection

Tags: java, glassfish, datasource, jtds

Does DataSource getConnection() method return a new Connection for each call or can it return an existing connection that's open by the same thread? Is this implementation dependent?

I am on glassfish 3.1 and using the jtds driver. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for jtds driver, it seems to create a new connection object for each call of [getConnection()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.2.4/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbcx/JtdsDataSource.java#JtdsDataSource.getConnection%28%29).

If you look further down into the `driver.connect(url, props)` call, it creates a new connection object using the driver (in the [connect()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.2.4/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/Driver.java#Driver.connect%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.util.Properties%29) method of the driver).

Comment: Thanks. Is there an established wayof tying a connection to a thread (request) till it's closed?